# How to print an Objective-C pointer with os_trace?

Tags: ios, objective-c, c, automatic-ref-counting, activity-tracing

I'm trying to se [Activity Tracing](https://www.objc.io/issues/19-debugging/activity-tracing/) in an iOS app, things have been working nicely up until I needed to print an Objective-C pointer.

In the slides for WWDC 14 Session 714 Apple mention that you can use `%p` to print pointers:

[image]

But I can't find a reliable way to do so without up setting ARC *(or myself)*.

I want to print the `NSManagedObjectContext` associated with a `NSManagedObject`, because I use multiple context I want to be able to see if I'm passing `NSManagedObject` to unexpected contexts.

1st try: **ARC forbids Objective-C objects in structs**

```
os_trace("doing something with object in moc %p", object.managedObjectContext);
```

2nd try: **Compiles but don't print what I want**

```
NSManagedObjectContext *moc = invite.managedObjectContext;
os_trace("doing something with object in moc %p", &moc);
```

The resulting trace prints `0x16fd0e6d0` while `(lldb) po invite.managedObjectContext` says that the pointer is `0x1741fce00`.

3rd try: **I can't believe this is the only way**

```
CFTypeRef moc = CFBridgingRetain(object.managedObjectContext);
os_trace("doing something with object in moc %p", moc);
CFRelease(moc);
```

This prints the address I'm expecting. But OMG having to manually retain/release something just to print the memory address is horrible.

What am I missing? There has to be a better way to do this.

Comment: Where you say "this isn't what I want" you define `NSManagedObjectContext *moc` perhaps you should pass `moc` as the argument to the format spec`%p`, not `&moc`.

Comment: @WeatherVane If I do that I get the same error O get on the 1st try version.

Comment: I believe `(void*)moc` is correct.

Comment: @WeatherVane you're right, with a little more because we need a bridge cast in ARC, so `(__bridge void *)moc`

Comment: @WeatherVane Feel free to add that as an answer and I'll mark it as correct. BTW the void cast also works with the 1st try code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct way of passing a pointer to the `%p` argument of a print formatter, is by casting it as `(void*)`.